# Nested CoordinatorLayout: Scroll not propagating to parent BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, bottomnavigationview

My `MainActivity` contains my main content as a `ViewPager2` as well as my `BottomNavigationView`, which has the `hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior`. Each ViewPager2 child uses the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` and in most cases, this causes the bottom nav to hide when a child fragment is scrolled, which is the desired behavior.

However, on my child fragment that contains a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"`, this behavior doesn't work. Removing the `scrollFlags=scroll` causes the bottom nav to act how it should. This leads me to believe that for some reason, the CollapsingToolbarLayout is intercepting the scroll behavior and it isn't propagating up to the bottom nav.

Any thoughts?

## activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_icon_tint"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
        app:backgroundTint="?android:colorPrimaryDark"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_navigation"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## fragment_devotional.xml (child of `ViewPager2`)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/background"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.ExpandedText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:title="@{devotional.title}"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:titleTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@{devotional.time}"
                android:scaleType="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                app:contentScrim="@color/background"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@{devotional.title}" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     ... content ....
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have a Coordinator Layout in another Coordinator Layout

the first CoordinatorLayout with the bottom Appbar doesnt get the scrolldata because the first one already consumes it.

what you need to do is to create a new type of Coordinator Layout that "communicates with the outer Coordinatorlayout (ie a nested Coordinator Layout).

```
public class NestedCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout implements NestedScrollingChild {

private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;

public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}

public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}

public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type) {
    int[][] tConsumed = new int[2][2];
    super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null);
    consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0];
    consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1];
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
    dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(View target, int type) {
    /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
    super.onStopNestedScroll(target, type);
    /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
    stopNestedScroll();
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes, int type) {
    /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
    boolean tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes, type);
    /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
    return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
    boolean tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
    return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled;
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(View target) {
    /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
    super.onStopNestedScroll(target);
    /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
    stopNestedScroll();
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    int[][] tConsumed = new int[2][2];
    super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, tConsumed[0]);
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null);
    consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0];
    consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1];
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                           int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
    dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onNestedPreFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    boolean tHandled = super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY);
    return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY) || tHandled;
}

@Override
public boolean onNestedFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    boolean tHandled = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed) || tHandled;
}

@Override
public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
    return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
}

@Override
public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
}

@Override
public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
    return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
}

@Override
public void stopNestedScroll() {
    mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
    return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed,
                                    int dyUnconsumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
}}
```

use this for the inner coordinator layout and everything should work hopefully :)

Comment: unfortunately the bottom nav is still not disappearing..not really sure what the issue is

Comment: Should this put as inner or parent coordinatorlayout?

Comment: This should be an inner layout